# I didn't understand how 16 is the output of the following code:

Tags: pycharm, python-3.7

I am doing the tutorial from the python page and no matter how hard I tried, I didn't understand how 16 is the output of this code. (needless to say that I googled (DuckDuckGo it actually) it before asking it here).

```
class MyClass:
    i = 12345

    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'    

x = MyClass()

x.counter = 1
while x.counter < 10:
    x.counter = x.counter * 2
print(x.counter)
```

This is the page from "Python Tutorial" https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple, by printing the value of x.counter during every iteration before and after multiplication we can receive the following values for x.counter:

```
class MyClass:
    i = 12345

    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'

x = MyClass()

x.counter = 1
while x.counter < 10:
    print('before', x.counter)
    x.counter = x.counter * 2
    print('after, x.counter)
print(x.counter)

before 1
after 2
before 2
after 4
before 4
after 8
before 8
after 16
16
```

We see that the value of x.counter doubles every iteration. The last time it enters as `8` and then is doubled to give us `16`. The while loop specifies that it will continue while x.counter is less than 10, now it has reached 16 it will stop.

Comment: Okay, now I don't see what does it have to do with the class method. sorry, I'm a bit slow and awake from 3am

Comment: Just a few minutes, I'm finishing another answer

Comment: @shv You create the variable `x` as an instance of the class `MyClass` and then you attach to it the property of `counter`, that is all. It is sort of like creating a dictionary, like `x = {}` and then `x['counter'] = 1`